# How to defeat Mesoamerican military without gunpowder?

Tags: warfare, weapons, military, tactics

**Question : What weapons, armors and tactics required to defeat mesoamerican armies without gunpowder?**

Assume that your army is made of native Texans unified under one leader.

**Clarification: Native Texans are native Americans in geographic area what we know today as Texas.**

Texan military manpower: 5,000
Mesoamerica Military manpower: 500,000

Conditions:

- You can use Iron and steel but not gunpowder.
- Texans have Bisons but no horses.
- Mesoamericans do not intend to take your soldiers as Sacrifice.
- No Bio war using diseases or poison.
- No firearms or related things such as cannons and grenades.

More details :

Year: 100 AD

**Texan Tech**:
Bow, Iron, Steel, tamed Bison as beast of burden, carpentry, Boat making, cloth making and small clipper sail ships.

**Tactics**:

Mesoamericans do fight in formations with blunt weapons such as stone axes and obsidian weapons. They will use other tactics such as hit'n'run, surprise attacks and baiting to lure and tire enemies while reserve armies envelope and surround them.
Although they take enemy soldiers as human sacrifice, consider them as post battle catching rather than active intent.

**Weapons**:

Blunt weapons although not made of Iron can still cave in or dent thin Iron and steel armor with enough force.

**Projectiles**:

Bow and Arrow has yet to spread to Mesoamerica. So Atlatls are used as projectile weapons.

**Armor**:

Ichcahuilpili - Mesoamericans use raw cotton gambeson that could protect from blunt weapons and arrows.

Comment: Do the natives have horses yet, because that is very important.

Comment: There were no Texans in 100 CE. The region was named Texas (pronounced roughly Teshas) by the Spanish in the $\rightarrow$ 17th $\leftarrow$ century. Using the name Texans is anachronic by more than a millennium and a half.

Comment: Hand grenades seem like they'd do the trick nicely.

Comment: Why not just look at medieval tactics?

Comment: @John Mesoamerican warfare is specialized in blunt weapons, something that german morningstars showed to be very effective against armoured units. And Mesoamerican gambesons were so good that spanish ditched their chainmail in favor of them. Classic medieval tactics do not deal with this specific combo and there are no well established counter for this outside gunpowder and diseases.

Comment: Tamed bisons are, kinda questionable. There's a reason none of the Native American tribes managed to effectively domesticate them

Comment: @Khaos321999: Guns were really not that much more effective than bow-and-arrows or slings (the latter even broke steel according to Spanish records.) Also, yeah, slings, why do you think the natives wouldn't have them? The original Spanish conquests really did not have that much to do with disease or gunpowder. So the Texans can fight pretty much like they did.

Comment: I'm staring to feel like we're doing celebrity death matches. "Pre-industrial south asians without bone weaponry vs. inuits with powerful metallurgy magic. Who would win?"

Comment: *How* do they have iron and steel? These developments don't just come out of nowhere. Did some proto-proto-Vikings manage to cross the oceans and bring iron-working technology, but not enough people to colonize? Was it a local development, and if so, how long have they been working on the secrets of iron and steel, and why haven't their neighbors picked them up? What are their production capabilities? Are they making tiny batches with great difficulty, or is it a major industry and widely used material for them?

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Stranded Timetraveler crashed in Texas @ 70 AD, coincidentally knows iron and steel making from science project. Attracts nomadic tribes by farming and catches Bison with their help for taming. As for Iron production, few villages next to iron sources produce iron for all of Texas but army has enough steel armament at 100 AD. Trade is sporadic during this time, and iron that leaves Texas is considered luxury good rather than a tool.

Comment: @Shamshiel, lack of horses is big.  The Spanish didn't make much use of gunpowder when attacking the Mesoamericans, true, but Spanish cavalry with steel swords and steel armor were devastatingly effective on the battlefield.

Comment: To answer this question is to either provide you a plan that will fall apart at first contact with the enemy or write the story of the defeat of the mesoamerican military for you. Either way this question will hinge entirely on how you choose to have events in your world play out. Such story based questions are not appropriate for this site.

Comment: (@AlexP I feel that is kind of a non-issue here: this scenario is clearly fictional, and, besides, words like "Americans" (as in "native Americans") have a similar 'problem'.)

Comment: @Mark: True, but I am thinking the magically-tamed bison OP posited may be able to provide a cavalry substitute, but perhaps when OP says "beast of burden" he doesn't want them riding them, though I am not aware of any similarly-sized beast of burden that isn't ridden and bison are very fast.

Comment: Just FYI the real Mesoamericans had bows, both the Aztec and Mayan had them.

Answer (score 6):

Given your 100 to 1 odds, the Texans are going to have a really tough time of it.  There are things like Asymetric warfare tactics that may help out, but it will take quite a bit of time before any attacks can be launched with any real chance of success.

**Start with Intelligence**

Anything you try is going to need a bunch of information first.  You will need spies to assess everything from where to strike, how to strike, who the opposing commanders are, what their weaknesses are, how they tend to react to which enemy action.  You need all of this in advance to plan your strikes.  Start by specifically targeting commanders who are not loved by their men and who are not popular among the higher ups.  Their areas of control are probably going to be kind of fertile for intelligence assets to subvert.

**Add some money**

Or other valuables.  You have the secret of steel, don't you?  That kind of empire already can outspend you is hard cash, but steel implements are far more valuable than just weapons.  Prosperity is also bound up with prodigious crops.  Farm implements may be almost as valuable as cash for bribes.  Steel tools might be useful in increase crop production.  Get the locals on your side.  They may not turn your spies in if you are helping to feed them.  Supplementing your armies with irregulars and other locals will help a great deal.

**Power to a point**

It would take a lot of time for word to spread throughout a 500,000 man strong army.  And messages can get muddled along the way.  You can use this if you can make strong, small strikes at the heart of power.  Capture the king, if you will.  Do it fast and the rest of the army won't even know you are there until it's too late.

**Discipline**

When it comes right down to it, a smaller force can take on a larger force with discipline and tactics.  Split your forces into 2 main groups and hide in the terrain.  Wait for the coming force of 10,000, reduce them in an ambush with ranged weapons then envelope them.  Superior arms and armor means you can defend a little more easily, but it is not the be all end all if you don't have an absolute game changer kind of weapon.

You can't do any of the above without information though, you need to hide for a while and gather as much information as you can.  Even then, the odds for you aren't great.  You are outnumbered 100 to one, and even primitive weapons can kill a heavily armored knight, eventually.

Good luck.  Probably should have waited about 1400 years to invade.

Answer (score 5):

AD 100 is way too far back for “Texans”. If it's Meso-America that you are interested in then its early even by Mayan standards (pre-classic period). But there was plenty of civilization even then such as around El Mirador and during the time of the building of the Pyramid of the Sun in Teotihuacan Mexico. There is not a lot to go on from this period but including some discoveries from later periods you could probably assume the following:

They are highly superstitious and base many decisions on necromancy and other animistic beliefs.

There are many different polities ranging from small nations, city states and chiefdoms.

Warfare was very ritualistic and involved a lot of parading in front of the enemy on open ground. An capturing the enemy was often harder than killing them.

With this in mind:

Try to find out where you are and what the political situation is, you might find ready allies to hand against a bigger rival power. Any form of interpreter would also be very valuable.

Most important – ensure your men know their drill, are well disciplined and fight as a coherent unit. The enemy will likely eventually charge as an irregular mob.

Expect attempts to enchant and cast spells as a way of defeating you in the run up to battle with a lot of parading in front of your men – make use of this with disciplined fire en-mass from archers especially with crossbows and then charge with cavalry if you have it.

Horses were driven to extinction in Palaeolithic times in the Americas, so the sight of cavalry is likely to panic the enemy especially on first encounters (they may even believe that man and horse are one creature).

If possible attack the warriors with the fanciest costume like an eagle or Jaguar or with a lot of coloured plumage as they are likely to be high ranking individuals who if slain will cause disarray in the enemy ranks.

Do not expect or try to take prisoners for questioning (the enemy knows what happens to prisoners). Do watch out for unconventional forms of attack. Thrown hornets nests can be deadly and armour would be little protection.

Show a healthy respect for the enemies Macuahuitl – wooden swords with obsidian blade implants. Probably an exaggeration but, there were reports that they could decapitate a horse.

Answer (score 3):

### Bison Chariots - Steel Crossbows

One defeats a Stone Age enemy with Bronze Age tactics!

(modified, in this case for steel weapons)

Bison can run at 35 mph, and a 12th Century steel crossbow had an effective range of 100m - that is, it was *accurate* up to 100m, and still deadly beyond that if fired in volleys.

Stone age mesoamericans would struggle to match either that speed of motion or that firing range.

### Chariot Tactics

Chariots are mobile, ranged weapons platforms. The first chariots were probably single warriors throwing javelins, but two or three man teams operating bows rapidly overtook them.

I'd propose a combination of 2 and 3 man groups. The two man team is optimized for speed, and the 3 man team for more firepower.

I'd suggest placing some hooks on the chariot such that the crossbowmen can use them to cock the bows more quickly: a loop of steel on the bow is placed in the hook near the floor of the chariot, and the operator does a squat or deadlift motion to arm the weapon. It probably takes some practice.

### Perfect Battle

The ideal battle probably looks something like the Mongol tactics in Eastern Europe: half your force in 2 man teams attacks the larger enemy. Soon after engagement, this group flees in apparent disarray. They run, and the larger host chases.

After a mile or two, once the enemy is winded and spread out, the 3 man chariots ambush from the sides, cutting the enemy host in half. The 2 man teams turn and re-engages.

The enemy is defeated in detail.

Ideally.

Answer (score 2):

**Texans use Fear**

Texans have steel and make full metal body armor. They also tamed Bisons, being able to make them charge at voice command.

Meso-americans don't have any of that, and also have legends and prophecies about metal gods that can command nature, are immune to weapons and breathe fire.
In a battle, your Texans showing up in full body armor will shake Meso-americans hearts and will make them want to flee. Add to this a hundreds of Bisons charging and they will outright panick and flee for their lives, praying to their gods to forgive them their arrogance in defying them.

PS : Your Texans don't do anything close to breathing fire, that's what the Meso-Americans added themselves to create a picture of their "Gods" ;-)

Comment: I like the war bison.  plus they make for tasty barbque

Comment: @PaulTIKI Brisket is a superweapon.

Answer (score 2):

### Technology gives you tactical options, but the aim is civil war

I think @codeMonkey has it right with 'Defeat the Stone Age using the Bronze Age'. I've got a mix of that and medieval methods, but the aim is to provoke a civil war.

The Spanish only had to win a few battles before all the enslaved Aztec / Inca peoples rebelled.
This is their single biggest weakness. You probably can't kill 100:1 in a setpiece. So don't try. Your enemies are loathsome, evil jerks to their own people. Use it. Pizarro and Cortes did, and you can too.

To set off their implosion:

### Better bows

North American bows sucked. Hard. The very best had a range of 100m, and those were up in Canada and Alaska. Most had an effective range of 50m. European bows could reach 300m by 1500 A.D. Asian bows could do the same, and in addition be fired from horses, etc,as well as the Chinese repeating crossbows.

This opens up all sorts of asymmetric warfare options, or allows the chinese crossbow equivalent of Crecy or Agincourt, where the sky turned black with arrows to the point that trained knights wept over it from PTSD for the rest of their lives.

### Alcohol and drugs

You have maize? And agave? Good. Selling bottles of liquor as fast as you can outside of battle will wreak economic, cultural and spiritual devastation upon the mesoamericans. Make cocaine, while you're at it. If you can just survive the battles for a while, you'll win the war. Heck, you will probably *command* lots of their soldiers by the end of it.
Don't forget the old 'invite them for a peace banquet then butcher them while drunk' trick. This has been reliably recorded in every ancient civilisation that had booze.

### Phalanxes

For a set piece battle with up to 20:1 or so, this is worth considering. If the mesos stay at a distance, kill them with bows. If they get close, kill them with phalanxes.

### Siege weapons

If you have steel, why not build mangonels and ballistae?

### Greek fire

I have little in common with a brave Aztec warrior. Refusing to be burned alive is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't going for a clean cut fair fight, you can use back handed tactics such as oiling the battlefield and setting it a flame. Tars and oils have been something in war for a very long time and it is common to burn enemies in war.

There are also tactics such as starving them out. When you have a larger army to fight against if you can steal/destroy their food source and make them wait it out, as long as the Texans have a safe place to avoid them. Then when they are weak from starvation, that is when you would have an attack happen.

Comment: Make Greek fire!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. of course, a qualified yes.

The longer the odds, the more has to go right and the less has to go wrong.

Composition:
I am a little surprised at hit and run and luring tactics being used in an army as large as the Mesos. Something that large needs significant coordination to fight as a force. I'll then presume that the Mesos have superior numbers, but have a tribal system of village levies or city-states that will band together, but are largely autonomous.

Goal:
I presume by 'defeat' you mean a force-on-force scenario and that there is no system of counting coup or political or resource objectives. If the reason for war was due to an unpopular pronouncement by the Meso king, then an information campaign and insurrection/rebellion by partisan forces could be orchestrated to 'defeat' the combined armies. The objective for conflict will dictate the method of engagement. I'll presume though that the goal is the destruction of the opposing forces.

Strategy:
If the above are both true, then the Tex want to mount a campaign of defeat in detail by concentrating force briefly, inflicting casualties and quickly pulling back. Protracted engagements would allow the Mesos time to call up units or move them to the engagement area. They need to keep the Mesos off balance. Short raids at night at random locations would also keep the enemy guessing, although the Tex want the Mesos to shift their combat power only to be confounded, so every raid should look like a large engagement.

In the middle term the Tex need to force the Mesos to expend more resources in chasing them than the Tex consume. Given the much larger civilization, the Mesos will have an early advantage in numbers and likely have more stockpiled resources, but they have more mouths to feed and equipment to maintain. If the Tex can keep lots of Meso units in the field, that's manpower not growing food, not repairing buildings and not knapping new flints. The Tex will have an advantage in the long term, so the main hitch is to last long enough.

In the long term the Tex want to reduce enemy combat power and mobility until the Tex can start to cut the Mesos off from their resources. If they can, say, take an obsidian quarry for a day or two, smash all the equipment and then take off, the Mesos not only have a supply interruption but now have to allocate manpower away from the military to repair the equipment. Forcing the Mesos thin by destroying food stores, fields and infrastructure will cause the society to be unable to sustain itself and continue to prosecute a war.

Engagements:
The Tex first need to scout the Meso areas heavily. They need to know as much as possible about where and how resources are gathered and used.

Attacks need to be fast and brutal to not only provoke and lure in a large response, but to inflict as much damage as possible in limited time until the Mesos can mass an effective counter.

Thin steel can be an effective shield against blunt weapons. The Tex don't need more than some spring steel plates in their coats. If they are good with spring steel and have windlasses from sailing, they can fashion various siege weapons like ballistae and mangonels. Fire would be fairly effective as a projectile. A clay ball of lamp oil with a rag wick would do the trick. A sheaf of arrows loaded in to a ballista would not be accurate, but would hit a wide area and do some injury, which is all that is needed. If the Tex are clever, they might fashion a cho-ko-nu type of repeating crossbow. It is entirely possible to build one with only wood and sinew. If they attached a geared cam and limbered it with a spring steel bow, you would have an incredibly effective high power rapid-firing weapon run by a team or two or three.

They should employ triangulation of crossfire for their heavy crew-served weapons and have multifunction foot units.
Each foot unit of about five should have:

- three halberdiers/short archers outfitted essentially like hoplites. A light breastplate and helm, a light, long shield, short sword, short bow and a short hafted spear or halberd.
- one heavy crossbowman in lighter armor with a buckler and side sword
- one light crossbowman/fire grenader in lighter armor with a buckler and side sword, for preference they should have a light cho-ko-nu.

The foot units' basic responsibility is to screen the siege weapons and not get caught in melee. They should probe and assault weaknesses, but pull back behind siege fire when challenged.
On approach, the heavy crossbow should engage first, with the footmen screening with their shields in a mini tortellum. Light crossbow can engage in high angle fire with flight bolts. In the middle distance, heavy crossbow should shift to high value targets as light crossbow fires at leading elements. If not in direct fire, footmen can engage with flight arrows. In the close distance the heavy crossbow should swap to sword and buckler, watch for flanking and pick a maneuver target. The light crossbow should switch to grenades, backed up by footmen on shortbows, or if the focus of an attack, footmen should continue screening.

Foot units should operate in threes. When pulling back from an attack, they should use bounding overwatch in reverse. Two units should establish a line in front of another friendly unit and lay heavy fire in to approaching enemy. One of the fire elements should then maneuver behind the friendly unit to the rear, which now becomes a fire element. Proceeding in this fashion they can pull back while covering themselves.

If the Mesos are not fanatical or professional, but are tribal levies of farmers and hunters, seeing scores of arrows being fired, balls of clay that burst and burn people alive and shiny soldiers racheting some machine that spits deadly arrows out 100 yards faster than you can swing an axe twice is going to give them pause.

The Tex would want to make their weapons largely wooden and transport them in parts that can be knocked together with toggles. That way they can easily take them down to pull back and in the worst case use a few firebombs on their own equipment. They don't want siege weapons falling in to Meso hands.

The Tex should make use of their ships to land raiding parties and assault Meso vessels with their superior ranged capabilities. Gliding along the coast at night and launching firebombs as far inland as they can at irregular intervals would also keep the locals on edge and raise general fear and apprehension.

The Tex should foster rebellion. They would be unable to take prisoners since they need to travel light and fast, so they should release anyone they capture. They should try to be as kind as possible to temporary captives and give the people a symbol or flag to put on their towns or fly to demonstrate their allegiance. No town with that symbol that does not have military in it should ever be bombed or attacked. If the Tex can turn the people against the military, especially if the military is a tribal levy, they might just send a representative out under a white flag to ask the Tex to please not burn or skewer them and in return they'll give them some food and water and pretend they never saw anything. At these odds, you want surrendering to be a very good idea.

Answer (score 1):

**What they need, fundamentally, is a Force-Multiplier**

This is more of a tangential answer, because at the moment, 100-1 is a significant force to overcome without a 'wonder weapon'.

However, The Texans do have one significant advantage - they are defending. Which means that their lack of numbers can be mitigated to a degree.

**forts, castles, terrain, engineering**

Here's our first area that the Texans can really mitigate the numerical odds - to reference the Battle of Thermopalae - if you can force the attacker into an area where they can't bring a numerically superior force to bear, you've made a good start.

If you look at Medieval Castle design, the Corridors were often only the width of a single Man's Shield, allowing one man to face hundreds... one-at-a-time.

So let's start with our Texans have known they would face invasion and have pre-built complex fortifications to channel the attackers.

**the Will to fight**

Everyone knows that if America wanted to, they could roll into just about any country and have tanks in the capitol within a matter of months, if not weeks, if not days.

So why did they withdraw from the likes of Iraq, Afghanistan and Vietnam?

The answer is the Will to fight - now, given that without a media system, it's harder to demoralize a populace to stop sending their husband's, sons and fathers to death - but the Will to Fight can still be a factor. It's why Sun Tzu talks about 'Death Ground' - if your only option is to stand and fight, you are motivated to stand and fight.

So our Texans are masters of psychological warfare.

I'm not just talking brutal and public displays of torture (although this can backfire - wanting to stop an evil people doing evil things is a good way to galvanize a populace).

Things like having an armor such that the Texans appear to be unkillable. Having a very standardized uniform that makes it difficult to tell if anyone has been injured or killed. Imagine you've spent all day attacking your enemy and you can see many of your compatriots bloodied and bruised - you look at your enemy and they appear uninjured and are laughing and joking.

**Logistics**

Amateurs study tactics, experts study Logistics.

Whilst not as much an issue for the Defenders (as supply lines tend to be shorter and less prone to disruption for a defender) - it's still a factor.

The Texans with their Bison are masters of resupply and ensure that their warriors are fed, watered *and rotated*.

In addition, understanding the importance of Logistics...

**500,000 men in combat require a lot of food and water**

Marching with kit on uses a lot of Calories. Fighting uses a lot of Calories. A 24 hr military ration pack pushes around 4,000.

That Food has to come from somewhere- and our Texans know it - they make sure to Harry and harass the supply lines to limit those supplies.

Remember the Will to Fight? Hungry soldiers are notorious for *accidentally* bad generals and then going home.

Answer (score 0):

Look to the actual past.  How did British colonizers of America wipe out massive amounts of Native Americans?  Biological Warfare.

With the arrival of British colonizers, new diseases from viruses and bacteria were introduced to the Native Americans, which had no immunity to their effects.  Smallpox and other diseases killed countless indigenous people in America.

Was this done purposefully?  Yes.  There is one documented case of intentional infection.  However, it was probably more.  Not to mention, all the transmission of disease from incidental/accidental contact.

Comment: The op specified no biological warfare.

Comment: @thequestioner ah, i missed that.  still, accidental exposure might come up regardless, due to any close combat fighting.

Answer (score 0):

### Mobility, logistics, and steel

your Texans are trained fulltime soldiers with calvary vs disorganized warriors who can't keep up. the Mesoamerican formation should breakdown once battle actually starts. And they can't counter the Texan armies speed.

**Bison** might actually make for better cavalry than horses, they are slower, but still a lot faster than humans. The have decent endurance and can turn a lot better than horse. They are also willing to charge an enemy, which is one thing that takes a lot of training to get a horse to do. But their biggest advantage is **logistics**. The biggest hinderance Mesoamericans had was they had low output agriculture, soldiers could not stay away from home for long because they were also the food producers. With trained bison your Texans have **PLOWS**, which means the have enough food surplus for fulltime soldiers. The also provide huge logistical support since their army can have **supply wagons**. These two things are a huge advantage, your Texans can wage war non-stop while the Mesoamericans have to stop or starve every few months. I would me remiss if I did not mention if your Texans have livestock they will have new fun diseases to surprise the Mesoamericans with, but maybe they have not had them long enough for this to have a strong effect.

In battle the bison are mostly only useful as cavalry, transportation, or pulling chariots. **Cavalry** is going to crush the Mesoamerican at first, they have no good counters. Bison unlike horses should have no problem charging a formation of soldiers and they can spin around once breaking through. This means they can break up and surround Mesoamerican formations. It is hard to overestimate the power of cavalry against those without cavalry.

**Transportation** Cavalry don't have ot be used in battle they can be used to get to and from the battle. This was done so you can move faster than the other army, meaning your Texans can attack before the Mesoamericans even know they are coming, always hitting faster than the Mesoamericans can even communicate much less prepare. Then the disappear before the any organized counterattack can come. The Texans are always fighting on their terms. Worse, or better depending on perspective, they can move their armies around to help each other much much easier than the Mesoamericans. Boats will just make this worse, with bison and boats counterattack, which is where the Mesoamericans will have the best chance, will be all but impossible. The Texans attack, loot, and then leave before the Mesoamericans can bring numbers to bear. this is why the Greeks, Mongols, and later the Normans were so hard to fight, they were too fast and mobile.

**Steel armor** is a huge advantage, we saw this when the Assyrians first figured out iron. Steel plate armor makes most stone or wooden weapons nearly useless. The Spanish were using armor made to counter firearms first and formost, which made them worse at dealing with melee, but they were still good enough for mesoamerican weapon to simply shatter against them. denting armor is fine, it happened a lot. That is armor doing its job absorbing a blow, a dent can be fixed. Most of your Mesoamerican weapons will actually be destroyed in combat against proper plate armor, which will have a huge phycological impact on top of disarming the attacker. Stone and wood weapons just do not have the durability to stand up to impacting steel armor. Actual medieval style plate armor, (anything after the 1400's) will make the texans terrifyingly resistant to most weapons. Combine them with shields and your Mesoamericans will barely be able to damage them. The real limitation will be heat, plate armor and hot humid conditions do not mix well, this is the only advantage the mesoamericans will have outside numbers.

**Steel weapons** like thrusting swords, spears, and axes will absolutely destroy your Mesoamericans. their armor and tactics are all wrong to deal with formations of armored spearmen. Even simple roman tactics will be devastating. Worse the Mesoamerican don't have good helmets, which is a huge liability. There is a reason one of the first used of metal armor in warfare is helmets.

**Archers** with easier to make iron arrowheads will likewise be absolutely devastating to Mesoamericans, especially in formations. Crossbows would be even better, since they are a lot easier to train. Gambeson does very very poorly against war type arrows or bolts. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uoz0eggQen8

As for **tactics** you have a huge selection to pick from, roman and Macedonian phalanx and calvary tactics which were copied by later medieval armies will be your best bet, but again you have a huge number to pick from. Moral is a huge factor in infantry combat and your Texans will be able to absolutely destroy the Mesoamerican moral and organization. they are almost impossible to hurt, attacking from monsters that can destroy formations, and using weapons that are extremally effective. your Texans are faster more mobile, much better armed and armored, with far superior logistical support, Numbers can't counter ALL of that.